# How to use phantomjs with python to post data?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
phantomjs 2.1.1
python 2.7.11
```

In the docs of phantomjs, I see this:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var postBody = 'user=username&password=password';

page.open('http://www.google.com/', 'POST', postBody, function(status) {
console.log('Status: ' + status);
// Do other things here...
});
```

But in python package, I can not find "open" function. If I want to use phantomjs with python to post data, what should I do?

I use phantomjs like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
...
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.customHeaders"] = headers

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:8910',  // conect with docker 
            # desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
            desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? and what is the error you have faced?

Comment: I want to use phantomjs  by "post" method to request website.

Comment: and what error have you faced?

Comment: no errors, I just don't know how to do.